# Yii Composite Key and Url parameters

Tags: php, yii

I've recenlty been stunned by a database with lot of composite primary keys (and related foreign keys friends XD). I'm developing an application using Yii Framework, i've created all the model and crud i need but i found that there is a problem with passing composite pk to create automatic urls.

```
--- view ---
// this generate a php warning
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/dosomething', array('id' => $model->primaryKey));

--- controller --
public function actionDoSomething(array $id) { ... }
```

This solution generate a warning because createUrl use urlencode internally and it just claim that second parameter should not be an array. Of course disabling PHP Warning let it works nice even if $model->primaryKey return an array instead of a scalar. But I want a "clean" solution to that problem!!! Any ideas? I was thinking about serializing/deserializing or encrypt/decrypt params to work with a single string, but honestly dont think is the best choice.

Comment: I suppose the primary key is not a single value. According to the documentation, the second parameter of [`createUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail) is actually a mixed too. Have you tried using `$model->primaryKey` directly as a second parameter?

Comment: yes i've already tried and it works but is like split the primary key in single values and so i cannot use (array $id) in my actions but i need to explicit handle every single field of the key!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the controllers methods don't receive any parameter, because they are accessed by `$_GET['field']`. Besides, Yii provides the method [`getActionParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getActionParams-detail), which does almost the same that you want:

**View:**

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/dosomething', $model->primaryKey);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionDoSomething() {
    $id = $this->getActionParams();
    // ...
}
```

---

### Edit

To get only the subarray containing the values you want, you can filter the parameters:

```
public function actionDoSomething() {
    $keys = array_flip(array("pk1", "pk2"));
    $id = array_intersect_key($this->getActionParams(), $keys));
    // ...
}
```

Or maybe even better, don't use any tricky solution and keep it explicit:

**View:**

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/dosomething', array('pk1'=>$model->pk1,'pk2'=>$model->pk2));
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionDoSomething(array $id) {
    // ...
}
```

But remember not to trust user's input and filter it, and parameters send to a controller are no exception.

Comment: Well since version 1.1.4 u can have a dynamic binding of parameters directly into the action arugments. Btw Your solution is limited, to give an example: let's suppose that you want to pass a composite pk + some other parameter, in this situation your solution will give an $id = composite pk + other stuff, so completely wrong!!! that's why i was looking for a dynamic solution!

Comment: @Th3N3rD Then that's responsibility of the logic to separate the correct values. I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: With composite pk these two instructions are the same:
`Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/dosomething', array('pk1'=>$model->pk1,'pk2'=>$model->pk2));`
and
`Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/dosomething', $model->primaryKey);`
However for now...just to make it works i will use it, even if when i'll add more parameters than it will be tricky to handle it XD.